# Copying links off Google Search results directly

Tags: browser, samsung-galaxy-tab, 4.2-jelly-bean

I Googled for one document, a PDF file. If I navigate to that link using my device browser, the document starts downloading. However, what I actually want is the actual URL to the document copied to my clipboard, not the Google link which redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Samsung Galaxy S2, running CM10.1

On my stock Browser, I can long-press a link. A menu opens, and one of the menu items is `Copy link URL`.

Comment: ***still scratching head as to how that worked***

Comment: @deostroll We learn something new everyday. ;)